# Iterating over a 2D list in python

Tags: python, list

I would like to iterate over a 2D list. I understand that I can do this with:

```
for j in range(columns):
     for i in range(rows):
        print depth[i][j],
```

But is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), or write a double-loop generator-expression like:

```
for (i,j) in ( (i,j) for i in range(rows) for j in range(columns) ):
    print depth[i][j]
```

or

```
for d in ( depth[i][j] for i in range(rows) for j in range(columns) ): ...
```

also, if you don't actually need the indices, but only to iterate over the *values* of `depth`, you can do:

```
for row in depth:
   for v in row:
      print
```

and even if you do need the indices, it is more pythonic to use `enumerate`:

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(depth):
   for col_index, v in enumerate(row):
      print 'depth[%d][%d]=%s' % (row_index, col_index, v)
```

Comment: Great!! But what if I want to set bounds for x and y. I have updated the question

Comment: Apply some problem-solving skills - figure out what values you actually want to use for each iteration variable, and set up the corresponding sequences to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with:

```
for depth in (depth[x][y] for x in range(rows) for y in range(columns)):
    print depth
```

#### Edit:

If you want bounds you can use the `min` and `max` builtins :

```
for x in range( max(x_min,col-2), min(x_max,col+3) ):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Although, I have updated the question. Any idea how I can achieve what I have mentioned in the edit?